# Intellij differentiate java from groovy files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, ide

I have a Intellij project with groovy and java files. Intellij Ultimate does not distinguish them by colour nor does it show file extensions by default. Is it possible to change any setting in the IDE to enable this distinction?

Comment: I guess intellij does not allow you change the default. See : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-types.html . (Note that groovy scripts have different icons..but not groovy classes)

Comment: Right. I have them all as groovy classes

Comment: They are distinguished by icons; java classes have round icons, groovy classes have square icons (with rounded corners). Classes opened in the editor can show extensions (at least in version 2016.1.2), the option for this is "Settings -> Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs ->Hide file extension in editor tabs". Don't think it is possible to show extension in the Project Tree.

Comment: Yes square and circular icons seem to be the only differentiating factor. Thank you @Steinar

Comment: @Steinar :  Square vs circle. I never noticed it. thank you. I guess should move comment to answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote this originally as a comment, but follows the suggestion by Jayan to move it to the answer section.

The classes are distinguished by icons; java classes have round icons, groovy classes have square icons (with rounded corners).

Classes opened in the editor can show extensions (at least in version 2016.1.2), the option for this is: "Settings -> Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs -> Hide file extension in editor tabs".

I don't think it is possible to show extensions in the Project Tree, but will happily edit this answer if someone points to the correct option for this in IntelliJ.